# jQuery AJAX request to PHP login not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

So I'm trying to do an inline login whenever the PHP $_SESSION['logged_in'] variable is not set. (this variable is set when I log a user in) The problem is that I can get my script to work when using multiple pages with header redirects, but trying to remain on the same page via AJAX requests to the login.php file is failing. Here's a look at my code.

the login form itself...

```
<?php 
      include ('global.inc.php');
        if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] == 1 ) {
            echo '<form id="addNoteForm"><label for="title">Title</label><input id="noteTitle" type="text" class="form-control" name="title"/>
                <label for="content">Content</label><textarea id="noteContent" class="form-control" rows="20" name="content"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="addNoteButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Note" />
                <button class="btn" onclick="cancelAddNote()">Cancel</button>
            </form>';
        }
        else {

            echo '<form id="loginForm" action="login.php" method="get" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input id="loginUsername" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="'.$username.'">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input id="loginPassword" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="'.$password.'">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit-login">Login</button>
                </form>';
            }
        ?>
```

jQuery AJAX request script

```
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#loginForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var username = jQuery('#loginUsername').val();
        var password = jQuery('#loginPassword').val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'login.php',
            data: 'username='+username+'&password='+password,
            success: function(data) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                   window.location.reload();
                }, 1000);

            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('AJAX login failed. Returned data = '+data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

here is the login.php file

```
<?php

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        require_once (__DIR__.'/includes/global.inc.php');

        $userTools = new UserTools();

        if ( isset($_GET['username']) ) {
            $username = $_GET['username'];
            $password = $_GET['password'];
        }

        if ( $userTools->login($username, $password) ) {
            return true;
        }

        else {
            return false;
        }
    ?>
```

the global.inc.php file

```
require_once (__DIR__.'/../classes/Note.class.php');
require_once (__DIR__.'/../classes/NoteTools.class.php');
require_once (__DIR__.'/../classes/User.class.php');
require_once (__DIR__.'/../classes/UserTools.class.php');
require_once (__DIR__.'/../classes/Database.class.php');


// connect to the database
$db = new Database();

// initialize UserTools object
$userTools = new UserTools();

// start the session
session_start();

// refresh session variables if already logged in
if ( isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    $user = unserialize($_SESSION['user']);
    $_SESSION['user'] = serialize($userTools->getUser($user->id));
}
```

and finally, the login script of my UserTools.class.php

```
public function login($username, $password) {

        $hashedPassword = md5($password);

        $database = new Database();
        $database->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password');

        $database->bind(':username', $username);
        $database->bind(':password', $hashedPassword);

        $user = $database->single();

        $user = new User($user);

        if ( $database->rowCount() == 1) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = serialize($user);
            $_SESSION['login_time'] = time();
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
            return true;
        }

        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I feel like I'm overlooking something minor here and need a fresh set of eyes to take a look at it. Like I said before, when I had a separate login.php file that upon successful login did a header redirect to a "welcome page", I had no problems with it. I think I'm having an issue with how I'm returning data to my jQuery function through AJAX. I dunno. Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: you don't send anything back from your login ...`return` is not an output statement

Comment: Even if I've edited login.php to echo out "logged in" or "failed", those will be returned but the $_SESSION variable doesn't seem to update

Comment: To help with debugging how about actually printing something in your login.php page then use `console.log(data)` in your AJAX success and AJAX error functions. (disable the page reload so you do not clear the log).

Comment: Yes, I've tried that too. Had login.php echo 'logged-in' on success and 'failed' on failure, then logged that to the console. The data is returned fine there

Comment: Stupid question, but all the well worth my while. I assume you are successfully logging in? (You've returned successful login messages?) If not, have you dumped your AJAX return data in the console?

Comment: I can only log in when I do it outside of this AJAX script. I setup a similar page that has the login form then upon success, it just does a header redirect to a "welcome" page. That welcome page displays the user's login info. 

This is why I think it has something to do with my AJAX script and not any classes or database work.

Comment: Information such as that helps, especially when debugging. You always want to think the following 1) what could cause this issue? 2) Where can I add variable_dumps or debug logging. 3) Always check your data, never take something for granted in programming. Have you checked your $_POST values? (Echoed them back in the console log?)

Comment: Yes, the POST variables are being passed without a problem. Any chance this could be a WordPress related issue? I've built this app on top of a WP install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a modsec issue set on the server by my web host. All is working now. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

Your are setting the ajax data in the wrong way, it is a array of objects and no a string

So, instead of

> data: 'username='+username+'&password='+password,

the data should be:

> data : {   username : username,   password : password }

Comment: I've tried passing it through as a JSON type string like that and I still end up with the same results. :(

Comment: I think that the problem could be with the session and no with the ajax.

What I'm almost sure if the data should be in a Json type.